Disable the default behavior of Bluetooth mouse right click as "Go Back" in Android Chrome by Javascript?
Can the default behavior of Bluetooth mouse right click as "Go Back" in Android Chrome be disabled by Javascript?
I tried event.preventDefault() without success
